# DirectShow Encoding dropped frames compensation

Tags: winapi, encoding, directshow, video-capture, directshow.net

I currently have a DirectShow graph in GraphEdit which looks like this:

```
      Source(USB WebCam) -> Encoder -> Mux -> File Writer
```

However, if the Source drops frames under recording, the encoder won't compensate for that loss.. Meaning if i have recorded 30 seconds of video, and dropped 20% of the frames (as an example) the resulting video would end with 24 seconds of video.

This means that everything in the video would be sped up by a factor of 1.2x which is absolutely not acceptable, I've replayed the video with VLC Player and WMP - same results. It's as if the encoder(?) or some other filter in the graph does not care about the lost frames.

Encoders I've used to reproduce this problem is WMV9 and a third party H264 Filter.

Even though the CPU usage is very high during recording, I really need to be able to handle and compensate for dropped frames so that the timeline of the video doesn't suddenly stop making sense. Is there a filter out there that handles this, or do I need to do something myself in the graph? What's actually happening here?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**
I have tried to build a much simpler graph using `Asf Writer` filter and also using an Audio Source as you can see in the attached photo.
                                                                             However because my Capture Source (Camera) loses frames, the end video ends up with a big sync issue meaning the audio length is way longer than the video and goes out of sync (instead of compensating) I Would have expected to see the video catching up to the audio.

[image: DirectShow Simple Graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you end up with a file of smaller duration (by the length of dropped frames), the problem is a likely bug in one of the filters in the pipeline.

Potential problems that might cause this behavior fall into two categories:

1. Multiplexer ignores dropped frames and contracts resulting file
2. One of the filters upstream to multiplexer is removing timestamps from the frames, which makes it impossible to "see" dropped frame and filters fall back (some multiplexers would abort with error instead) into assuming continuous video sequence

   - the problem might also take place if you use preview output of web camera instead of capture output

Comment: Hello Roman, I have updated my question with an Edit - can you look at it? How come video and audio goes out of sync in such a basic scenario? Even if i dropped frames, should it not compensate for lost frames with black frames (or similar) so that the video and audio remains the same length and doesn't go out of sync? What am I doing wrong? _Edit: It should be noted that my end graph won't contain an audio source, this was just to test dropped frames._

Comment: I suspect your video source delivers frames without time stamps, or incorrectly stamped. You can use GraphStudioNext's built in Analyzer Filter to check what timings are attached to frames, whether the frames are stamped continuously or have information about skips.

Comment: I've attached the Analyzer Filter, and the information looks correct as far as I can see. I'm really at a loss at what my next move is, I've attached a snippet of the Analyzer info so that you can see. [Attached Picture](http://i.imgur.com/X0zaJLl.png)

Comment: The snapshot looks like "no drops" continuous feed at around 57 ms/frame speed. When there is a frame drop you should see a gap in the time stamps. Do you see it?

Comment: Yes, the snapshot i posted has a gap it goes from 57ms/f to 300ms/f suddenly. This must be where it dropped frames, correct? I am assuming that that is fine as the time stamp is correct?

Comment: The fifth column "frame start time" should have had a matching gap in time stamps. And it does not have it and shows continuous feed. Looks like a source filter (or whatever time stamps the frames) bug. This matches the symptoms you describe that duration is contracted and resulting file has no trace of dropped frames. If the problem takes place as early as in source filter, apparently no other filters would fix or compensate for the problem. It looks like you are to do it yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84461/discussion-between-nicholas-and-roman-r).